# the antidervative of this function

Tags: integration

Is this correct:

## $\int$ $\frac{du}{(3u)} = $ $\frac{1}{3}$$\int$ $\frac{1}{(u)}$ $du$

To

## $\frac{1}{3}$$\int$ $ln(u)$ $du$   = $\frac{ln(u)}{3}$+ C

Or should I use u-substitution?

I checked out wolfram and it turned out okay, but wanted to be sure.

Comment: as long as we're talking natural log here.

Comment: Yes you are correct here. This is the natural logartithm rule just append a absolute value to the u.

Comment: You have an extra step here that is wrong though.. $\frac{1}{3}\int \frac{1}{u} du \ne \frac{1}{3}\int \log(u) du$. Just cut out the $\frac{1}{3}\int \log(u) du$ term and everything is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that
$$ \log u = \log_e u = \ln u $$
Here are the steps
$$ \int \frac{1}{3u}du = \frac{1}{3}\int \frac{1}{u}du = \frac{1}{3}\ln |u|+C $$
However
$$ \frac{1}{3}\int \ln u\ du \not= \frac{1}{3}\ln |u|+C $$
So although your final answer is correct, your last equality is incorrect.